# Significance test on interobserver variability

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variability

I am pretty new to statistical testing.
So here is my (completely revised) problem:

I have **n observers** reading the same **m datasets** consisting of **k parameters**.

For every parameter $k_i$, I therefore have $n$ observations. I have analyzed absolute and relative difference (difference divided by mean), as well as bias for every parameter and every pair of observers (in a Bland-Altman-Analysis).

I want to use a generalization of the Dependent t-test for paired samples - I think this is correct since all **n** are measuring on the same data pool.
My question is:

1. How can I find out if one observer significantly differs from the
   rest?  Say - observer $n_i$ "sticks out" from all others, either in
   general or in a pairwise comparison.
2. Should I test the mean values of all, or their standard
   deviations or both?
3. How can I formulate the correct $H_0$ and $H_1$ for the problem?
4. Is the Dependent t-test for paired samples the correct test for this problem?